# Desktop doesn't appear after login

Tags: unity, 14.04, compiz

I updated my packages recently (I suppose to a newer kernel; I don't really know). Once I restarted, my desktop wouldn't display after I typed in my password. I did what others said and installed `compizconfig-settings-manager` and enabled but that didn't solve the problem. I also tried `dconf reset -f /org/compiz/` but it tells me

> error: cannot autolaunch d-bus without x11 $display

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had this very trouble this morning. After little investigation I found that update installed new linux-image without installing linux-headers for it. To fix it takes several minutes.

When you logged in and stack at empty desktop press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. This switches you to a tty console (simply put into command line login). When there enter you name and then password. when prompted. After you logged in, enter into console this command:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

This will install missing header files. After this enter the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

This will reinstall the new linux image and will configure it properly.

Then enter

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

On the next reboot your system should be fine.

Comment: What do you mean by Linux-headers-$?

Comment: Actually, I did it and it didn't work.

Comment: I know that this is old but to know if this is your problem, you can try to start Ubuntu with another linux-image (in grub select the option of more ubuntu options and select another image from the list).

Comment: And some times instead of reinstall it, you can try to remove it if it's causing problems.